# JavaScript return and how errors are caught with its usage

Tags: javascript

In the below code the error from get() is not caught in getExtended().

```js
async function get() {
    throw new Error('err in get');
}

async function getExtended() {
    try {
        return get();
    } catch(err) {
        err.message += 'err in getExtended;
    }
}
```

but if I store the return value of get() in a variable then return it's caught in the try-catch. Also this can be caught by doing a .catch() after the get.

Does return implicitly return to calling function regardless of state? What's going on here?

Comment: Note that in the first piece of code you call `get()` without `await`

Comment: when you just return get(), you are not awaiting it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have an async function within `try-catch` phrase and you like to catch the exception you must use :

```js
async function getExtended() {
    try {
        return await get();
    } catch(err) {
        error.message += 'err in getExtended;
    }
}
```

as the `get` function is defined as `async`, must say needlessly in the demo code you gave.

Comment: Thank you this worked! I was under the impression that `return` and `return await` were the same, especially as return seems to always resolve. What is the difference?

Comment: Found an article with the answer here https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/. 
"By returning [get()], we're deferring to its result, so our catch block never runs."

Thanks for the help!

Comment: they *act* the same when they are not under try-catch phrase. but if you want to catch an error in `async function`, you must wait for it.